# Отнять даты Y-m-d H:i:s и получить раздницу в днях минутах и секндах

Tags: php, дата, datetime

Доброго времени! Вопрос такой пытаюсь отнять от даты дату Y-m-d H:i:s от Y-m-d H:i:s и получить раздницу в годах месяцах часах минутах и секундах всвязди с этим соорудил вот такую дьявольскуб астралябию:

```
 $happyday = "2016-05-13 17:00:00";
$curday = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $d1 = strtotime($happyday);
    $d2 = strtotime($curday);
    $diff = $d1-$d2;

    $diffv = $diff/(60*60*24);
    $days = floor($diffv);//дни

    $mdays = $days*(60*60*24);
    $hiff = $diff-$mdays;//обратно

    $hours = $hiff/(60*60);
    $hoursv = $hours;
    $hours = floor($hours);//часы

    $myhous = $hours*(60*60);
    $miff = $hoursv-$hours;
    $minnv = $miff*60;
    $minn = floor($minn);

    $sec = $minnv - $minn;

    $sec = floor($sec);

    echo "Дней ".$days." Часов ".$hours." Минут ".$minn." Секунд ".$sec;
```

очень сложная конструкция получилась хотелось бы спросить - есть ли способ по проще? и к тому же почему то правильно высчитывает только Дни и часы (?) есть ли по проще метод как произвести такое вычитание или подскажите пожалуйста где я тут в расчетах произвел ошибку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В PHP > 5.3 есть несколько специальных классов для работы с датой/временем ([`\DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php), [`\DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.dateinterval.php)). Эти классы предоставляют невероятно удобный API.

К примеру, если вы хотите просто получить разницу между двумя датами, вы можете использовать вот такой код:

```
$happy_day = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2016-05-13 17:00:00');
$now = new \DateTime('now');

$diff = $now->diff($happy_day);

echo(sprintf(
    'Days: %u, hours: %u, minutes %u',
    $diff->d,
    $diff->h,
    $diff->i
));
```

Помимо прочего, интерфейс `\DateInterval` позволяет получать разницу в месяцах и годах, не утруждая себя вопросами "*а сколько в этом месяце дней?*" и "*а сколько високосных годов было между этими датами?*".

Answer (score -1):

Есть повод проще. Есть такая операция как % - получение остатка от деления.

Таким образом если в переменной `$s` разница дат в секундах, то

```
$sec = $s % 60; // получили секунды
$s = (int) $s / 60; //получили число минут

$min = $s % 60; // получили минуты
$s = (int) $s / 60; //получилио число часов

$hour = $s % 24; //получили число часов
$day = (int) $s / 24;
```

Comment: Этот путь очень плохо работает для получения разницы между датами в месяцах и годах.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, я в курсе. Но этот путь работает везде. Независимо от используемого языка и его версии. Ну и развивает алгоритмическое мышление, а не умение копипастить примеры из документации не задумаваясь

Comment: Я посмотрю на ваш код, когда вы реализуете правильное вычисление месяцев и годов. Вангую оверхед ~100 строк, которого можно легко избежать используя встроенные функции выбранного ЯП.